# Pysolr search multiple queries with and

Tags: pysolr

How to search multiple queries and require the "and" for q.op?

```
import pysolr
solr = pysolr.Solr('..url../solr/'+name,always_commit=True)
solr.search("test:test")
```

I want to add searching for also "url:http://test.com" as an "AND" q.op parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will test this soon, but currently it looks like:

```
solr.search("test:'test'\nurl:'http://test.com'",**{
    'q.op':'AND'
})
```